# Laravel add extra method when user register

Tags: php, laravel

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    //need to add this when user post register form
    protected function activationCheck($data){
        $count = User::where('email', '=', $data['email'])
                    ->where('active', '=', 0)
                    ->count();
        if ($count == 1) {
            return redirect()->to('login')->with('warning', "Your haven't active your email");
        }

        return something; //pass to validator

    }

    $this->activationCheck(Request $request);
```

I need to add a method to check user email active state before validation & create.

My problem are

1. how can I start this method when controller receive request
2. how can I return and pass to validator? (do I include this method in middleware? if so how?)

Comment: You want to check if a email with status 0 is already exist at the time of user regitration?

Comment: i want to check if user already sign up but havent active his/her email yet (check 'active' column)

Comment: making the email validation as unique would do that.

Comment: And you should check whether an email is active or not during login

Comment: i did, but the reason I want to check is because, if user accident delete active email, I can resend it

Comment: so if they not active yet, tell them and give them another button to resend it if they need

Comment: If user accidentally deletes email how can you get them back? and for resending the activation link you can make a separate method for that.

Comment: You can call your method if method authenticated exists in the `AuthController` it will be called from Laravel `trait AuthenticatesUser`

Comment: You can make your own middleware for status check with login.